# Add an input value to a database value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project where I have to add a database value to in input value.

```
<div>
    <div class="price">680</div>
    <div class="price">
        <input type="number" name="name">
    </div>
</div>
```

In above code 680 will come from the database. Here I want to add an input number to that 680. I am very new to jQuery.

**My JavaScript code is**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $("input").keyup(function(){
            var priceList = $('.price');
            $.each(priceList, function(i, price){
                total += parseFloat($(price).text());
            });
            alert(total);
        });
    });

</script>
```

In this it outputs "NaN".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In this it outputs "NaN".

You get this message since you're trying to loop through `div`'s and parsing the text of them, when it's empty. You need to loop over `input`'s instead.

You could init the `total` with the database value then loop through the `input`'s and add the parsed values to total in every iteration.

**NOTE:** Use `input` event instead when you track the user input since it's more efficient.

**Multiple inputs:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var db_val = parseFloat($('.price:first').text());
  var total = 0;

  $(".price input").on('input', function() {
    var total = db_val;

    $('.price input').each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    });

    $(".total").text(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="price">680</div>
  <div class="price">
    <input type="number" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    <input type="number" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    <input type="number" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="total">680</div>
</div>
```

**Single input:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var db_val = parseFloat($('.price:first').text());
  var total = 0;

  $(".price input").on('input', function() {
    var total = db_val;

    total += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;

    $(".total").text(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="price">680</div>
  <div class="price">
    <input type="number" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="total">680</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here you go**

```js
var result = 0;
var price = +$('#price').text();

$('input[type="number"]').on('input', function() {
  var val = +$(this).val();
  result = parseInt(val + price);
  $('#price').text(result)
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="price" id="price">680</div>
  <div class="price">
    <input type="number" name="name">
  </div>
```